Dramatic increase in New User accounts - why?
I've noticed a big uptick in "new user" account creation on Bicycles:

Zooming in, we can see a cliff between 5 and 12 June 2024.
Before that, new users were steady at 6-15 a day.   After that cliff, we're seeing 91-155 a day.

I had been searching for something else, and stumbled on this.   The new users look like boring "normal" names, many have gmail addresses from a spot check.
There's no appreciable increase in posts of questions or answers, or their quality.
Bicycles has a solid seasonal swing, but this is an aberration.

Are other sites seeing this?
Is it because of the suggested "login easement" changes recently?
Is this beneficial or just more junk accounts that will clutter up the user database ?

These new users don't do anything like post Q or A or comment; I suspect they're just reading posts and somehow acquiring a user account.

@dragonrage from Arqade shows a similar shape, but twice as large.   https://i.sstatic.net/Yj1djITx.png

langdev.se does NOT show the same pattern, according to @lyxal  https://i.sstatic.net/Wixqu2uw.png

Could you provide a link to the SEDE query you used? This would allow us to check other SE sites as well.

@galacticninja I was poking around the Moderator's Analytics page, not using SEDE.    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics?from=20240219&to=20240818&host=&report1=users    Frankly SEDE scares me.

CS.SE shows a similar increase.  Could this because of the new pop-up window encouraging people to create an account with their Google credentials?

@testing-for-ya I guess I'm raising it with SE in case its an indicator of something larger, or teh result of a change made in that week.

On ServerFault, it's a more dramatic jump, right after the Jun 1,2 weekend, it jumped from 150/day midweek to 550/day, going down to 300ish on weekends.

Also on MSO: Why did Stack Overflow sign-ups spike in the past two weeks?. There was (is?) a bug that users having Google account would have their SE account automatically created.

network wide: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1856641#graph

@MetaAndrewT. I've edited that highly misleading title. Accounts are only automatically **re-**created for users who have previously created them. That clearly wouldn't explain the behaviour here, which is presumably from one-click account creation. The account re-creation is bad, I agree, but zero-click Google authentication with no previous authentication would be a critical privacy incident across the internet and we can't confuse the two.

Back in April, we communicated about an experiment that would make signups much easier. Many of those changes were rolled out due to the experiment's success. However, as noted by others, some bugs ended up causing accounts to be recreated in addition to those created by the more straightforward signup method.
While we saw account creation go up network-wide, this did inflate those numbers in some places. The bugs that caused that were all fixed as we discovered them.
As far as seeing some accounts that might come off as junk accounts, there was a bug that impacted some of our mechanisms that prevent spam accounts from being created for a short time. That bug was also addressed and corrected.

"due to the experiment's success" - how exactly you define "success"? Just sheer number of new accounts?

UPDATE: Not the answer
This answer was written under the assumption that accounts were being created automatically when logged in with a Google account. The actual issue, as described in the linked bug report, is that accounts are being recreated, which is, as explained by Jeremy in a comment, unlikely to account for such a significant increase in new accounts.

Original answer
Seems that new user accounts are being created automatically by visitors who are logged into google accounts.
Being logged in with a Google account automatically recreates Stack account
A spot check of 20 new users shows all of them have gmail.com addresses.
Downside - all these new users will be oblivious, and likely never come back which dilutes some statistics while artificially raising the "total users" count.

"while artificially raising the "total users" count" doesn't that mean "success" in SE speak?

Presumably, also validates their (recent?!) actions in SE speak.

That post's title is misleading (I've now edited it). The bug isn't creating new accounts out of nowhere, it's re-creating accounts for users who previously had them. That scenario wouldn't be common enough to explain this change. It's the one-click login that's probably responsible, not zero-click automatic account creation.

Senior Leadership must have a "new account creation" metric that their bonus is based on.  Defeating the metrics without accomplishing the goal is a time-tested tradition of C-level executives everywhere.

@testing-for-ya   I was initially wondering if they all had some kind of pattern that would relate the users.    Something like   "ihateSE-4567@gmail.com" followed by "ihateSE-4568@gmail.com"   to link the accounts.   I also checked other details looking for indications of socks.    I only went looking at PII after noticing the uptick.

@Criggie Why do you say this is not the answer?

I took significant liberties editing this to explain why you added the update portion. Please either adjust it or revert it entirely if this doesn't fit.
